# Draw partial sphere in Cesium

Tags: javascript, cesiumjs

I am trying to draw a partial sphere in Cesium, representing the coverage area of a radar. However, I can only find documentation in Cesium for drawing a complete sphere, as shown in [this](http://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Apps/Sandcastle/index.html?src=CZML%20Spheres%20and%20Ellipsoids.html&label=All) example.

How can I draw a partial sphere, given a location and a min/max azimuth and elevation?

Comment: Dome geometry is part of the [Cesium Pro](https://www.agi.com/products/cesium-pro/) set of primitives.

Comment: Thanks @JasonM1. I came across Cesium Pro the other day, but so far I have been unable to figure out how to get/buy it.

Comment: Someone asked this on there forum. (How to get Cesium Pro) https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cesium-dev/oUl8RIgOO98

Comment: There is also a [Cesium Sensors plugin](https://github.com/AnalyticalGraphicsInc/cesium-sensors) that has advanced volume geometries but was implemented with an older version of Cesium. Someone could take over this project and update to latest Cesium.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never did find an existing solution to this, so I implemented it myself and submitted it back to the Cesium team. As of 1.62, Cesium supports partial ellipsoids. See the new [Sandcastle example](https://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Apps/Sandcastle/?src=Partial%20Ellipsoids.html&label=Geometries).